# Angular SPA Redirect Login Loop when Third Party Cookies are blocked

Tags: angular, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

I have an Angular SPA using oidc-client w/ IdentityServer4 hosted on two different domains. Users that have blocked third party cookies in their browser settings are getting stuck in an redirect loop.

The root of the redirect loop appears to be the CheckSession IFrame not being able to read the idsrv.session cookie value, which generates a new hash there by kicks off the silent refresh loop.

Here is the SPA's UserManager config:

```
    authority: oidcAuthInfo.authority,
    client_id: oidcAuthInfo.clientId,
    redirect_uri: ${baseHref}auth-callback,
    silent_redirect_uri: ${baseHref}silent-refresh.html,
    post_logout_redirect_uri: ${baseHref}welcome,
    response_type: 'code',
    scope: openid profile ${oidcAuthInfo.apiName},
    filterProtocolClaims: true,
    loadUserInfo: true,
    revokeAccessTokenOnSignout: true,
    automaticSilentRenew: true
```

Are there any alternative login/flows or workarounds to allow browsers that block third party cookies?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact solution to your problem. But generally, identity server lives under subdomains of main sites like.

login.microsoft.com
account.google.com

So having the Identity server under subdomain makes things much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I am expeciencing exactly the same problem,and after a lot of research the only partially working solution was to add FrameAncestors in my UseCsp in my Startup.cs . I only made it work with dummy value :

```
branch.UseCsp(options => options
                    .DefaultSources(s => s.Self())
                    .ConnectSources(s => s.Self())
                    .ScriptSources(s => s.Self().UnsafeInline().UnsafeEval())
                    .StyleSources(s => s.Self().UnsafeInline())
                    .ImageSources(s => s.Self().CustomSources("data:"))
                    .FontSources(s => s.Self())
                    .FrameAncestors(s => s.Self().CustomSources("dummy"))
                    .ReportUris(r => 
r.Uris("https://my.reporturi.io/r/default/csp/enforce")));
```

and basically it is throwing now

"Refused to display 'https://localhost:44326/connect/checksession' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' dummy"."

So the infinite loop is gone but this error above appears.
Any ideas how to fix it as well?